# Monty Python first mention of Gorn -- related to STOS?

Tags: star-trek, monty-python

[Gorn at around 40 seconds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T70-HTlKRXo)

This is the first time I noticed Python using this word. I have not watched the entire video but I suspect no monster in a clunky lizard suit.

Comment: I imagine its just a Britishism, a contraction of "go on" or "gone". As in "gorn home" (from the same skit).

Comment: So you `... have not watched the entire video` eh? Well to be fair Python sketches are well known for their extremely long runtime. NOT.

Answer (score 7):

In context, it's pretty clearly that he means 'gone'. He uses it in a sentence slightly later;

> **Chapman:** *Oh dear, I suppose she'll be gorn for a few days now.*

This pronunciation was (and remains) [moderately common among the upper classes](https://www.theguardian.com/uk/2001/dec/23/monarchy.comment), and would have been recognisable by TV audiences in the 1950s and 1960s.

Comment: And the upper classes are rumored to be Reptilians... food for thought.